# Passing a variable through raw sql - Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am currently trying to pass through a variable to act like a where clause so I can pass it to the URL and display content for each event on a page.

To do this, I'd need to pass the event_id.

```
public function exportSearch($event_id){

        $query = "SELECT
                    u.prefix AS  'Title', 
                    u.forename AS  'Forename', 
                    u.surname AS  'Surname', 
                    u.telephone AS 'Mobile Number',
                    u.email AS  'Email Address', 
                    ea.checkin_status_id AS 'checked in',
                    u.update_time AS  'Register Date', 
                    eg.name AS 'Event Group Registered', 
                    e.name AS  'Session Registered', 
                    u.bio AS 'User Information',
                    u.dob AS 'Date of Birth',
                    u.company AS 'Company',
                    u.company_role AS 'Company Role',
                    CONCAT(u2.forename, ' ', u2.surname) AS 'Guest of',
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question1,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question2,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question3,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question4,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question5,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question6

                    FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_groups AS eg on e.group_id = eg.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u2 ON ea.guest_of_user_id = u2.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id


                    GROUP BY ea.id";

           // $query->params([':event_id' => $event_id]);

        $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
        return $sqlDataprovider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
                'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                'sort'=>array(
                    'attributes'=>array(
                       // 'event_name'=>Event::model()->getAttributeLabel('name'), // csv of sortable column names
                        //'Question1' => EventAttendees::model()->getAttributeLabel('Question1'),
                        // 'Forename',

                    )
                ),
                 'pagination'=>array(
                 'pageSize'=>$count, //Show all records
        ),
            ));
     }
```

My idea was to use $query->params to do this and then throw it over to the view but had no luck.

It needs to display something like WHERE ea.event_id = $event_id but I can't seem to pass it through via the raw sql.

Comment: Please show a sample with content of the parameter $event_id the use you would do of this param .. .. and if is possible explain better what do you want obtain

Comment: I am populating data in a gridview based on the event id that is passed in the URL. I want the SQL I'm using to grab data based on the individual id to match up with the ID I'm passing in the URL, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add WHERE clause in your SQL like that:
`WHERE ea.event_id = :event_id`. Remember, your `$query` variable only contains SQL, so this is a string, not a something-like query object.

To pass parameter to `queryScalar()` function you need to pass an array which contains params. According to [`queryScalar()` documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail):

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar(array(
    ':event_id'=>$event_id
));
```

**NOTE:**

Documentation says:

> Executes the SQL statement and returns the value of the **first column
>   in the first row of data**. This is a convenient method of query when
>   only a single scalar value is needed (e.g. obtaining the count of the
>   records).

So, your first column is `u.prefix AS  'Title'` is string. Using it as `$count` its not a good solution. I suggest to write one SQL for getting count of rows, and other for getting data that will be passed to `CSqlDataProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

The sql should be this

```
    "SELECT
                u.prefix AS  'Title', 
                u.forename AS  'Forename', 
                u.surname AS  'Surname', 
                u.telephone AS 'Mobile Number',
                u.email AS  'Email Address', 
                ea.checkin_status_id AS 'checked in',
                u.update_time AS  'Register Date', 
                eg.name AS 'Event Group Registered', 
                e.name AS  'Session Registered', 
                u.bio AS 'User Information',
                u.dob AS 'Date of Birth',
                u.company AS 'Company',
                u.company_role AS 'Company Role',
                CONCAT(u2.forename, ' ', u2.surname) AS 'Guest of',
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question1,
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question2,
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question3,
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question4,
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question5,
                MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question6

                FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

                LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_event_groups AS eg on e.group_id = eg.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u2 ON ea.guest_of_user_id = u2.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id 

                WHERE ea.id = " . $event_id . " 

                GROUP BY ea.id"
```